# What are the possible method to simulate the dynamics of rigid bodies in simulation?

Tags: simulations, rigid-body-dynamics, molecular-dynamics

I just want to know the name of the methods, the simulation physicist uses to simulate the dynamics of rigid bodies.
Eg. Impulse Based Dynamics developed by Mirtich

Comment: This is far too broad a question for this site. There are textbooks, technical conferences, and entire journals devoted to this subject, and the techniques continue to evolve.

Comment: I agree. I thought that if any simulation expert is here, he may suggest something. I will post this to researchgate as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question may be better suited for the [scicomp SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). Having said that, common methods (at least for molecular dynamics simulations) are:

- [SHAKE](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021999177900985?via%3Dihub)
- [RATTLE](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021999183900141)
- [LINCS](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/%28SICI%291096-987X%28199709%2918%3A12%3C1463%3A%3AAID-JCC4%3E3.0.CO%3B2-H)

You can find a more thorough presentation of these methods on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_(computational_chemistry)).

Simple rigid bodies can also be directly simulated by using quaternions or orientation matrix. For instance, [here](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.474310) is a simple-ish algorithm based on orientation matrices I have used a few times that works really well for simple spherical rigid bodies.

Answer (score -1):

Simulating the dynamics of rigid bodies is equivalent to numerically solving differential equations. A few numerical methods for differential equations include the Runge–Kutta methods and Euler methods.

Comment: This isn't "wrong" in the literal sense of "wrong", but it's too vague to be of any practical use.